# За якими ознаками визначають історію походження запозичених слів?

Tags: етимологія, історія-мови, запозичені-слова

За якими ознаками визначають історію походження слів, запозичень з інших мов? У нещодавньому питанні про *кермо* є відповідь із `кърмъ`, а інші відповіді посилаються на німецькі слова. Пошук інших синонімів, *стерно*, швидко знаходить `дав.рус. - стърнъ`, але потім додано, що запозичено з польської. Яким чином може бути одночасно і "дав.рус.", і "запозичено з польської"?

Чи й досі мають ту саму вагу визначення лінгвістів, які працювали за часів заборони української мови (найчастіше пошук етимології слів закінчується словником Фасмера)?

Чи існують сучасні праці, які переоцінюють результати?

Comment: не зовсім зрозуміло, на яке саме питання з наявних чотрирьох ви хотіли би отримати відповідь

Comment: Програма-максимум - розгорнута відповідь, яка заторкне всі вказані проблеми. Програма-мінімум - хоч одне з них.

Comment: можливо за [цим посиланням](http://www.nativlang.com/linguistics/historical-linguistics-lessons.php) ви знайдете відомості, які можуть слугувати наводкою у пошуку відповіді на перше запитання.

Answer (score 3):

Пишу цю відповідь як покажчик, повідки я докопав, і звідки хочу відштовхнутись, покращити розуміння питання.

---

Починається все з теорії розвою конкретної мови. Сюди включають географічні та історичні особливості існування нації:

- хто були сусіди (задає тло для запозичень),
- хто мігрували через територію заселення,
- як змінювалась територія заселення,
- хто ким володів

  - політичні мотиви керування,
  - термінологія,
  - видавництво, типографія,
  - свобода розвитку релігійних переконань,
- які бар'єри існували

  - географія - гори, ліси, болота;
  - закони;
  - податкова політика - куди із сусідніх сіл йтимуть на ярмарок.

Письмові пам'ятки дають змогу вивчати розвій мови майже безперервно. Значні складнощі виникають, коли письмових пам'яток ще не було, але й тоді маємо змогу дізнатись дещо через непрямі докази - іноземці конспектували топоніми, звичайно, в транскрипції, близької до фактичної вимови.

Але тут стикаємось із проблемою, що російські лінгвісти з імперських та радянських часів намагались надати російській мові першочергове значення у порівнянні з українською. У багатьох питаннях це навіть смішно, але деінде важко сказати:

- чи є грецький запис назв порогів індикатором фрикативної вимови `г`
- чи є словник Мелетія Смотрицького (перевірю, чи того я автора вказав) індикатором, що саме вважалось руською мовою

  - дивіться, там пояснюється, як на "словенську" перекладається "руське" слово "лазня"
  - також, знаходимо "руське" слово "фрасувати"
- що малось на увазі під "простою" мовою, коли литовське діловодство мало вестись "по-простому"

  - простолюдинська мова, щоб була зрозуміла черні?
  - чи самоназва "руської"?

Письмові пам'ятки дають змогу порівняти, коли з'являються нові слова, та як вони пов'язані з попереднім правописом цього або інших слів. Якщо помітне значне відхилення від теорії розвитку - маємо справу із запозиченням. Приклади:

- свердло, простирадло - запозичення

  - в праслов'янській мові суфікс -dlo існував, але в українській мові зник
- друге повноголосся відбулося тоді-то и тоді (не знаю, які обмеження існують), тому спостерігаємо масову заміну редукованих перед такими-то приголосними на повноголосні склади

  - якщо помічаємо слово, яке з'явилось в інший період, або не підпало під це правило - все, маємо справу із запозиченням

Інші мовні процеси, характерні для української:

- асиміляція приголосних
- спрощення приголосних (заміна складних заднєязикових на простіші, та переміщення звуків ззаду вперед рота: *рука* - *руці*)
- ствердіння приголосних перед `і` та `є` (заміна `і` на `и`, `є` на `е`)
- злиття `ы` з `и`
- ствердіння губних приголосних (*кровь* - *кров*, діалектичні *здоровля*, *мнясо*)

---

От, і, зважаючи на все це, як тоді приходять до висновків щодо запозичення аж з німецької через польську "звичайних" слів, як *кермо*? Чим не підходять простіші процеси, типу другого повноголосся, якщо маємо звістки про давньоруське слово `кърмъ`?

Answer (score 2):

> За якими ознаками визначають історію походження слів, запозичень з інших мов?

Мені суб'єктивно здається, що основною опорою є авторитет тих чи інших дослідників. Бо людина без справді широкого і глибокого знання мов, не обробивши значну кількість інформації і джерел, не може висувати вірогідні гіпотези. А таких людей одиниці. Тобто є окремі «стовпи», на авторитет яких опираються подальші дослідники. «Стовпи» теж помиляються, але довіри до доморощених ентузіастів, в яких «столиця» походить від ста лиць — ще менше. Хоча сучасні, технології, мабуть, дозволяють ретельніше обробити інформаційну базу, а не опиратися на окремих талановитих людей.

> Яким чином може бути одночасно і "дав.рус.", і "запозичено з польської"?

По-моєму, запросто:

- або дві різні версії;
- або за природою слово давньоруське, але його забули, а потім повторно (можливо, в трішки іншому вигляді) запозичили в поляків <sub>(наприклад, слова «вуй» і «стрий» — давньоруські і, мабуть, раніше вживалися й на тій частині Русі, що зараз є Росією; але окрім західної України їх зараз майже не вживають (навіть в самій Україні); а як раптом буде сплеск популярності західної України і масові запозичення звідти — вони запозичать частково-своє ж слово; типу Русь→Україна→звуження області вжитку лише до західних областей→РФ (яка теж має право на частину спадщини Русі, тобто своє ж слово повернулось))</sub>.

На два останні запитання, на жаль, не можу відповісти. (Та й ця відповідь — як вилами по воді.)

Comment: ну, щоб "забули", треба, щоб на його місці існували інші синоніми, я так розумію. Дякую за спробу, я зараз напишу свою відповідь, яку не маю наміру приймати, а лише як зразок звідки хочу відштовхнутись у цьому питанні.